# Unable to connect via SSH to when eth0 is disconnected

Tags: raspberry-pi, network-interface, ip, mac-address

I've seen a few similar questions, to this one, but have not found a solution. I'm working on a Raspberry Pi and wiring up a second Ethernet port (ultimately it will be the only port on a Pi Zero, prototyping is just easier on a working device).

The interface shows up (`eth1` below):

```
pi@rpi42:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.13  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::10a1:563b:4056:9f04  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd87:1ceb:4c8c:1:cd55:9c53:b1c2:85b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether dc:a6:32:73:38:d2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 59958  bytes 15803023 (15.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 742  bytes 84166 (82.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.56  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fd87:1ceb:4c8c:1:fa0:37de:a0c4:30dd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::78d1:81ff:fed5:b9a0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7a:d1:81:d5:b9:a0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6913  bytes 2239414 (2.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 118  bytes 11356 (11.0 KiB)
        TX errors 66  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2  bytes 198 (198.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2  bytes 198 (198.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

...and the IP address matches on my network controller. However, in order to get the IPs to match I had to set a static IP and then set it explicitly on `eth1`, eg. `sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.56/24`. Also, I'm having to set the MAC address with systemd:

```
[Unit]
Description=Set MAC address for w5500 module
Wants=network-pre.target
Before=network-pre.target
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth1.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth1.device
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/ip link set dev eth1 address 7a:d1:81:d5:b9:a0
ExecStart=/sbin/ip link set dev eth1 up
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm hoping to disconnect `eth0` and to still be able to ssh into the device, but no such luck. **I can ssh into the device using either IP address when `eth0` is connected, and neither when it is not.** I'm not sure if the IP addresses for these interfaces should be the same or different, and it doesn't matter to me either way.

Here's the output of `route -n` if that helps:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    203    0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     203    0        0 eth1
```

I'm over my head here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to connect two interfaces in the same ethernet broadcast domain, using the same IP LAN. Usualy you do neither of this: interfaces should be in distinct Ethernet networks (prevents ARP issues with ingress) and distinct IP LANs (prevents routing issues with egress). Here you have routing issues (and this masks the ARP issues lurking behind). Is there a compelling reason you are doing this? Of course it's possible to make it work with complex routing settings (that the `route` command, obsolete on Linux, doesn't support), but is it worth the effort?

Comment: Thanks. You're helping me clarify my question/thinking. The compelling reason is that I need to move this to a Pi Zero and don't want to use WiFi long-term (and there's not an ethernet port). I should have said that I have the same problem in that case, i.e. wlan0 vs eth0. Does that help any? I simply want to connect a W5500 and have it work as though it's native to the device. It also may be worth noting that if I don't configure static IPs on the device and on my network controller, the W5500 winds up with a 169.254.* IP address after 3-4 minutes.

Comment: Using a wireless interface as client rules out setting up a bridge. Take a look at this SF answer of mine, where there's a description of what to do for *static* addresses, so you get an idea.  Integration with using DHCP would be the actual difficult thing. SF Q/A: https://serverfault.com/questions/900385/ghost-ping-on-a-multi-nic-linux-system/900958#900958

Comment: that SF answer concentrates on ARP in the explanations because OP said policy routing was already set up. Anyway the actions in the answer do also configure policy routing, just don't explain it much.